# How can I generate a report to display all users' access to a site?

Tags: 2010, powershell, permissions, script, reporting

I would like to generate an Excel (or CSV) file to have a list of all users and what type of access they have to a certain 2010 site? This site is secure, but I do have administrative permissions to it.

I have tried a couple PowerShell scripts on it, but they generate blank .csv files. Am I doing something wrong with them?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The following JSOM code worked for me to get all the users of a 2013 site, not sure about 2010. Openn the site in chrome. Copy the whole code and run in console. Doesn't work in IE.

```
var JSONToCSVConvertor = function (JSONData, ReportTitle, ShowLabel) {
        var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;

        var CSV = '';
        //Set Report title in first row or line
        //CSV += ReportTitle + '\r\n\n';
        //This condition will generate the Label/Header
        if (ShowLabel) {
            var row = "";
            //This loop will extract the label from 1st index of on array
            for (var index in arrData[0]) {
                //Now convert each value to string and comma-seprated
                row += index + ',';
            }

            row = row.slice(0, -1);

            //append Label row with line break
            CSV += row + '\r\n';
        }

        //1st loop is to extract each row
        for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
            var row = "";
            for (var index in arrData[i]) {
                row += '"' + arrData[i][index] + '",';
            }
            row = row.slice(0, row.length - 1);

            CSV += row + '\r\n';
        }

        if (CSV == '') {
            alert("Invalid data");
            return;
        }

        //Generate a file name
        var fileName = "MyReport_";
        //this will remove the blank-spaces from the title and replace it with an underscore
        fileName += ReportTitle.replace(/ /g, "_");

        //Initialize file format you want csv or xls
        var uri = CSV;
        return uri;
    }

    var cleanUp = function (a) {
        a.textContent = 'Downloaded';
        a.dataset.disabled = true;

        // Need a small delay for the revokeObjectURL to work properly.
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href);
        }, 1500);
    };


    var exportToCSV = function (resultRows) {
        var csvstring = JSONToCSVConvertor(resultRows, "", true)
        var testanc = document.createElement('a');
        if (testanc.download !== undefined) {
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            var mimeType = 'text/plain';
            var blob = new Blob([csvstring], {
                type: mimeType
            });
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.href = url;
            link.download = _spPageContextInfo.webTitle+'_UsersInfo.csv';
            link.dataset.downloadurl = [mimeType, link.download, link.href].join(':');
            link.innerHTML = "Export to CSV";
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.onclick = function (e) {
                if ('disabled' in this.dataset) {
                    return false;
                }
                cleanUp(this);
            };

            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        }

        else {

        }
    };

    var dlg = {};
    if(window.SP&&SP.UI&&SP.UI.ModalDialog&&SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose){
        dlg = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose('Downloading file','Please wait')
    }
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();
        var users = web.get_siteUsers();
        context.load(users);
       var csvsstring = '';
         var usersarray = [];
        context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
            var enumer = users.getEnumerator();
            while (enumer.moveNext()) {
                var currentUser = enumer.get_current();
              //  console.log(currentUser.get_title());
               usersarray.push({
        Id:currentUser.get_id(),
        Title:currentUser.get_title(),
        Email:currentUser.get_email(),
        LoginName:currentUser.get_loginName()
               })
            }
    exportToCSV(usersarray);
    if(dlg.close){
        dlg.close()
    }
        }, function(s, a) {
            alert(a.get_message())
        });
    });
```